# How to disable a lsp server using a specific rule?

Tags: neovim, lsp

I'm on a vue project, and I installed both `tsserver` and `volar`, but both of them will be called up when I open a `*.ts | *.js` file.
But for vue project I only want to use volar since both `tsserver` and `volar` take up nearly 1G of RAM in my current project and both have completion suggestions mixed up together.

Can I some how set a rule like if detected `vite.config.js` or `vue.config.js` then shut down `tsserver`, or detected `volar` running then shut down tsserver.
or some other way?

I'm using `lazy.nvim` and `mason-lspconfig`, this is my lsp setup func:

```lua
local setup = function(_, opts)
  local on_attach = require("plugins.configs.lspconfig").on_attach
  local capabilities = require("plugins.configs.lspconfig").capabilities

  -- after
  local lspconfig = require "lspconfig"

  -- List of servers to install
  local servers =
    { "lua_ls", "gopls", "html", "cssls", "tsserver", "jedi_language_server", "jsonls", "bashls", "prismals", "graphql", "volar", "sqlls" }

  -- require("mason").setup(opts)
  require("mason").setup()

  require("mason-lspconfig").setup {
    ensure_installed = servers,
  }

  require("mason-lspconfig").setup_handlers {
    -- default setup
    function(server_name)
      lspconfig[server_name].setup {
        on_attach = function(client, bufnr)
          on_attach(client, bufnr)
        end,
        capabilities = capabilities,
      }
    end,

    ["lua_ls"] = function ()
      require("custom.configs.mason-lsp.lua_ls")(on_attach, capabilities)
    end,
    ["volar"] = function()
      require("custom.configs.mason-lsp.volar")(on_attach, capabilities)
    end,
  }
end
```

and this is my volar setup:

```lua
local util = require "lspconfig.util"

-- local global_ts = "~/AppData/Roaming/npm/node_modules/typescript/lib"
local function get_typescript_server_path(root_dir)
  local found_ts = ""
  local function check_dir(path)
    found_ts = util.path.join(path, "node_modules", "typescript", "lib")
    if util.path.exists(found_ts) then
      return path
    end
  end

  if util.search_ancestors(root_dir, check_dir) then
    return found_ts
  else
    vim.notify("No typescript server path found!", vim.log.levels.ERROR)
    return
  end
end

return function(on_attach, capabilities)

  -- ps: the dynamicRegistration didn't seems to work, is there something wrong?
  capabilities.workspace.didChangeWatchedFiles.dynamicRegistration = true

  require("lspconfig").volar.setup {
    capabilities = capabilities,

    on_attach = function(client, bufnr)
      pcall(function()
        client.resolved_capabilities.workspace.didChangeWatchedFiles.dynamicRegistration = true
      end)
      if client.resolved_capabilities then
        client.resolved_capabilities.workspace.didChangeWatchedFiles.dynamicRegistration = true
        vim.notify "dynamicRegistration loaded for volar"
      end
    end,

    on_new_config = function(new_config, new_root_dir)
      new_config.init_options.typescript.tsdk = get_typescript_server_path(new_root_dir)
    end,

    filetypes = require("custom.configs.utils.npm_func").is_npm_package_installed "vue"
        and { "typescript", "javascript", "javascriptreact", "typescriptreact", "vue", "json" }
      or { "vue" },

    root_dir = require("lspconfig").util.root_pattern "package.json",

    documentFeatures = {
      documentFormatting = {
        defaultPrintWidth = 60,
      },
    },

    -- ps: don't know why, these settings never works
    settings = {
      vue = {
        autoInsert = {
          dotValue = true,
        },
        updateImportsOnFileMove = {
          enabled = true,
        },
      },
      typescript = {
        preferences = {
          -- "relative" | "non-relative" | "auto" | "shortest"(not sure)
          importModuleSpecifier = "non-relative",
        },
      },
    },
  }
end
```

Comment: Maybe should you tell us which plugin you are using to connect to the language server ([mason-lspconfig](https://github.com/williamboman/mason-lspconfig.nvim), [coc.nvim](https://github.com/neoclide/coc.nvim), [nvim-lspconfig](https://github.com/neovim/nvim-lspconfig))

Comment: thanks, i added some details @VivianDeSmedt